# How to place two elements (image and text) in a one row

Tags: html, css

Im writing some code using **HTML** and **CSS** only. And in header i have 1 image and some text after it. I need to place them in a one row to make it look like a normal header.

I was trying to use *display: inline-block* but it not worked for some reason

```css
 header{
        display: inline-block;
        width: auto;
    }
```

```html
<header>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" height="35" width="35" />
    <h1>Learn about your game</h1>
</header>
```

Comment: You can use `header > * {...}`. Because adding `inline-block` to header means that header will be displayed as inline-block, not it's children... you can specify that all children must be inline-block by using the code i mentioned above, or to set it directly to the `img` and `h1`

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works!

Answer (score 1):

Using `flex`

```css
header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.image-text {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
.image-text__image {
flex: 0 0 auto;
padding: 1em;
}
.image-text__image img {
display: block;
}
.image-text__text {
flex: 1 1 auto;
padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<header>
 <div class="image-text">
  <div class="image-text__image">
   <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" height="35" width="35" />
  </div>
  <div class="image-text__text">
   <h1>Learn about your game</h1>
  </div>
 </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Flexbox:-

```
header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
}

header h1 {
  padding-left:20px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
header{
            display: flex;
            width: 90%;
            flex-direction: column;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            margin: 20px auto;
            background-color: red;
            text-align: center;
        }
        header img,header h1{
            display: block;
            width: 80%;
            margin: 5px auto;

        }
    </style>
```

add this to your css